# Dynamic table format

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

i have this table to display data from my database dynamically

```
<table border="1">
        <th>PO</th>
        <th>Fuel Details ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Liters</th>
        <th>Previous Balance</th>
        <th>Hobo</th>
        <th>Truck ID</th>
        <th>Fuel Source</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Number of Vans</th>
        <th>Stripping</th>
        <th>Truck ID</th>
        <th>Customer ID</th>
        <th>Driver ID</th>
        <th>PO ID</th>
        <th>Waybill ID</th>

        <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_po_id_po']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['id_fuel_details']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_liters']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_previous_bal']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_hobo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_truck_id_truck']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_fuel_source_id_fuel_source']; ?></td>

            <?php do { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_date']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_route']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_destination']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_van_no']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_strip_stuff']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_truck_id_truck']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_customer_id_customer']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_driver_id_driver']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_po_id_po']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_waybill_id_waybill']?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_PKDD = mysql_fetch_assoc($PKDD)); ?>
        <?php } while ($row_PKFD = mysql_fetch_assoc($PKFD)); ?>
</table>
```

the first  displays the first instance if the program finds two or more data related to the first  it will make another  which is in the below code as you can see my problem is when i display the first  and the first instance of the second  are aligned but when the program finds another data related to the first  it will make another  but not inline on the second  i want it to show that the first  will be aligned with the first instance of the second  and the second instance of the second will be below the first instance of the second

[image: What is being displayed]

[image: What i want displayed]

The first picture shows what is displayed by the code

the second picture shows what i want to display

Comment: There's a distinct lack of / confusion about `<tr>` and `</tr>` in that script. That is your issue.

Comment: i added pictures i really dont get the confusion on the tr can u point it out?cause im really confused about the tr confusion thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>PO</th>
        <th>Fuel Details ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Liters</th>
        <th>Previous Balance</th>
        <th>Hobo</th>
        <th>Truck ID</th>
        <th>Fuel Source</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Number of Vans</th>
        <th>Stripping</th>
        <th>Truck ID</th>
        <th>Customer ID</th>
        <th>Driver ID</th>
        <th>PO ID</th>
        <th>Waybill ID</th>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_po_id_po']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['id_fuel_details']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_liters']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_previous_bal']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['fuel_details_hobo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_truck_id_truck']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_PKFD['tbl_fuel_source_id_fuel_source']; ?></td>

            <?php 
            if(!mysql_fetch_assoc($PKDD)){
                ?><td colspan='10'></td><?php
            }else{
                ?>
                do {
                    $i=0;
                    if($i > 0){
                        ?></tr><tr><td coslpan='9'></td><?php
                    }
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_date']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_route']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_destination']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_van_no']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['delivery_details_strip_stuff']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_truck_id_truck']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_customer_id_customer']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_driver_id_driver']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_po_id_po']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_PKDD['tbl_waybill_id_waybill']?></td>
                    if($i > 0){
                        ?></tr><tr><?php
                    }
                    $i++;   
                } while ($row_PKDD = mysql_fetch_assoc($PKDD));
            } 
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_PKFD = mysql_fetch_assoc($PKFD)); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: this code just gives me the other data on the right side not below

Comment: can you explain what you mean? your structure is quite fishy.

Comment: the row_PKDD are two or more data based on on row_PKFD so on on row_PKFD i can have 2 or more row_PKDD. I just want the row_PKDD when there is more than one to be below the first row_PKDD not below the row_PKFD data

Comment: OK. See the update on my answer. Also you can exchange the rows according to your requirement.

Comment: i just want the data on PKDD that are 1 or more to be inside the the row of the PKFD that is only one.Basically a table row inside a table row. Image on you see the date below the first row that is the 2nd data of PKDD which i want to be below PKDD not below PKFD data. like on image 2

Comment: this code doesnt display the second data for PKDD only the first data @raheel shan

Comment: ok see the updates you need a condition to generate colspan and also dynamically close and open row according to the data available. It would be better if you provide some sample php code

Comment: how can i add a table row below the right side of the table like float right?

Comment: you need to assign td, colspan property. you can't do that thing directly.

Comment: i will look into the colspan property thank you for your help.

Comment: has the above answer solved your problem? you can accept then

Comment: it didn't solve it yet but i think this will lead me to it.One last thing did you understand what i was trying to do? on the images? i posted above?

Comment: yes and the second image , you can not leave some space under the first row telling the browser to leave the space as it is and move you columns to the right side, for this you need to use colspan.

Comment: can you help me again? modify the code? im really new to this if else thing on php, can u help me with this algorithm, if(PKDD>=2)Colspan on PKFD = 10